# Does net.tcp switch to net.pipe (aka Named Pipes) if it's on the same machine?

Tags: c#, wcf

Someone once told me that in WCF if you use a net.tcp binding but connect to a service that is actually on the localhost it will actually use a net.pipe binding underneath.  I'm not sure if the address of the service needs to be localhost, the local IP, etc.

Is this true?  Has anyone tested this?  Is there any overhead?
Will using net.tcp inter-process open a socket back to the local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it doesn't do that. That would be extremely confusing when things don't work the way you expect them to.

Comment: I agree -- it was an assertion that is claimed to come from an iDesign class w/ Juval Lowy.  I was just curious if the experts here had any insight :)

Comment: FWIW, I have most of his books here, and I too have taken some of his classes, and I don't recall having seen or heard him claim anything like this.